# Long 'cold start' of android app caused by 'inflater.inflate()'

Tags: android

I'm trying to sort out long cold start of my application - it takes 5..10 seconds depending on (I'm not sure) state of Android OS.

After adding some `System.currentTimeMillis()` throughout the code I identified that roughly 50% of that time goes into `((LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(...)`

Startup inflates with best performance look like following:

1. Main View - **0.4s**
2. Sub View (wrapper around list view with header and footer) - **0.6s**
3. Inner list view - **1.5s** (20 rows, first one takes ~0.1s .. last one ~0.02s)

*(Phone is running on Snapdragon 820 + Android 8.1/LineageOS 15.1)*

After I click through application and return to that same View - entire initialization including all inflates works approximately 10 times quicker and performance seems to be rather good.

So the question is - any ideas how to improve performance of inflates at cold start?

(I suspect this is caused by Android Java VM is being warmed up, but 10+x times perf difference seems suspicious. If that is the case - then probably there is nothing i can do)

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by a bad layout structure. 
See [this](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout) page and try to optimize your xml layout as per the guidelines.